# I am not able to install the autocomplete-python package in atom text editor

Tags: python, error-handling, autocomplete, package, atom-editor

Downloaded Anaconda for Python and then installed the autocomplete-python in atom text editor

autocomplete-python traceback output:

Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **probably** need to download py.exe (or is it python.exe? I'm on a mac so I don't know) for the autocomplete to work. You can get it from the Microsoft store.

This is just a suggestion that may be the answer. You didn't clarify your question so I'm just assuming you didn't try getting python (which you can get from [the official python site](https://www.python.org/downloads/))

Comment: Well, did you download python itself?

Comment: No, What should I I download then?

Comment: download the python.exe from the microsoft store if you are on windows. If you're on a mac, it should already be installed